# A question about two-square sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $b$ is a factor of $a^2+(a+1)^2$, then there exists $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $b=(bx+(2a+1)y)^2+y^2$.

I think it is true, but I have no idea to prove it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there a typo in the last equation? You have $b>(bx+\dots)^2$ but $b$ is a natural number. Additionally, just plugging in any old example, say, $a=1, b=5$ leads to a contradiction. Why do you think it is true?

Comment: @David,for example, $a=1,b=5,x=-1,y=1$, then $5=(-5+3)^2+1^2$.

Comment: ah, $x$ is an integer, my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general claim is as follows.

> **Claim.** Let $m$ and $n$ be coprime positive integers, and let $b$ be a divisor of $c=m^2+n^2$. Then $b$ can be represented as $b=u^2+v^2$ with $b\mid um-vn $.

*Proof.* In Gaussian integers, write $c=(m-in)(m+in)$ and $b=(u-iv)(u+iv)$ with $u-iv\mid m+in$ and $u+iv\mid m-in$ (by putting conjugate prime factors of $b$ into corresponding parts). Then $b\mid (u+iv)(m+in)=(um-vn)+i(un+vm)$, so in particular $b\mid um-vn$. $\square$

Now, to answer the question, notice that $b\mid 1^2+(2a+1)^2$ and apply the claim. Then put $y=v$ and $x=(u-(2a+1)v)/b$.

Comment: How to choose $u,v$ such that $b|um-vn$, I doesn't get it in your proof. If you means for any $u,v$ there is  $b|um-vn$, I think it is false, as the same reason on the answer above.

Comment: We choose $u$ and $v$ so that $u-iv$ divides $m+in$. Then the desired divisibility follows as explained.

Comment: oh,oh, I get it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Very beautiful question. For the partial proof of the problem we will use 2 lemmas:

> $n$ can be written as a sum of $2$ squares if and only if, for every prime $p$ such that $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, the exponent of $p$ in $n$ is even. (This is the [Two Square Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem)) $(1)$

> If a prime $p$, $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ divides $a^2+b^2$, then $p$ divides both $a$ and $b$. (This comes directly from quadratic reciprocity) $(2)$

Lets begin the proof:

By $(2)$, if there exists a prime $p$ such that $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and $p|b$, then $p|a^2+(a+1)^2$, so $p|a^2$ and $p|(a+1)^2$. However, $a$ and $a+1$ are relatively prime, so $a^2$ and $(a+1)^2$ are relatively prime, so $p$ cannot divide both $a^2$ and $(a+1)^2$.

So there is no prime $p$such that $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and $p|b$, so by $(1)$, $b$ can indeed be written as a sum of 2 squares.

Let $b=u^2+v^2$. We will assume that $u$ and $v$ are different from $0$. Take $y=\pm v$. To complete the proof, we must show there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $bx+(2a+1)y=u$.

To complete the proof, we must only show that $u\equiv \pm(2a+1)v\pmod{b}$.

Comment: you take $y=v$ and $x,y$ such that $bx+(2a+1)y=u$, why $y$ can satisfy the two conditions at the same time?

Comment: You are right, that doesn't work. My excuses. I will edit

Comment: Why not? By rising to $\frac{1}{2}$, $u$ goes to $\pm u$, $v$ goes to $\pm v$ and $-1$ goes to $\pm c$. I think I have to still analyze when $b$ is a perfect square, so one of $u$ and $v$ might be $0$.

Comment: I know, I am fixing it. It works but I forgot to add the explication.

Comment: just a simple example, $a=6,b=85,u=9,v=2$, it is still wrong.

Comment: $c=2a+1=13$, so $u\equiv\pm cv(\mod b)$ is not true.

Comment: You are right. I clearly made some mistakes (I am sorry). I will leave the first correct part in, as a partial proof. I will maybe come later to try to continue. G'day